# Is Application() a Class or a function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, the follow sample code is from a webpage.

I think that Application() is a class, and UIApp is inherited from the class Application().

But in Android Studio 3.01, the hint of  Application() is displayed as a Method, you can see the iamge, it make me confused!

**The Image of the hint in Android Studio 3.01**

[image]

```
class UIApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        var instance: UIApp by NotNullSingleValueVar()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    class NotNullSingleValueVar<T> {

        private var value: T? = null

        operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T =
                value ?: throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} not initialized")

        operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
            this.value = if (this.value == null) value
            else throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} already initialized")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class cannot inherit a function.

You're inheriting the Application class, which has only one constructor, which is the empty constructor

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: Thanks, but why is the hint of Application() displayed as a Method in Android Studio 3.0 ?

Comment: Again, it's a constructor, not a method. Methods have return types. `public Application()` has no return type